# Java Code Optimization(jsoup)

Tags: java, optimization, jsoup

Is there an efficient way to optimize this code, as most part of it look like identical, I just started learning jsoup and dont know how really can do that ://

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.blocket.se/hela_sverige/bilar?ca=11&cg=1020&w=3&md=th").get();

Elements partOne = doc.select("a[title=Flera bilder]");
for (Element element : partOne) {
    String myElementOne = element.attr("abs:href");
    System.out.println(myElementOne);

}
Elements partTwo = doc.select("a[title=\"\"]");
for (Element element : partTwo) {
    String myElementTwo = element.attr("abs:href");
    System.out.println(myElementTwo);

}
Elements partThree = doc.select("a[title=Bild]");
for (Element element : partThree) {
    String myElementThree = element.attr("abs:href");
    System.out.println(myElementThree);

}
```

Comment: Why not write a function with Elements as parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `partOne`, `partTwo` and `partThree` blocks are basically identical; just replace all of the parameter differences with variables and extract to a method:

```
void someMethodName(Document doc, String selector) {
  Elements partOne = doc.select(selector);
  for (Element element : partOne) {
    String myElementOne = element.attr("abs:href");
    System.out.println(myElementOne);
  }
}
```

Example invocation:

```
someMethodName(doc, "a[title=Flera bilder]");
```

Alternatively, if you have access to Guava:

```
Iterable<Element> it = Iterables.concat(
    doc.select("a[title=Flera bilder]"),
    doc.select("a[title=\"\"]"),
    doc.select("a[title=Bild]"));
for (Element element : it) {
  String myElement = element.attr("abs:href");
  System.out.println(myElement);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Andy's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35481039/2229229) is of course doing the job. However, since you asked specifically for ways optimizing the JSoup calls, I would suggest to learn more about [CSS selectors](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) and [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/). For example this will do fine in your case:

```
Elements allParts = doc.select("a[title~=^Flera bilder$|^$|^Bild$]");
for (Element element : allParts) {
    String elStr = element.attr("abs:href");
    System.out.println(elStr);
}
```

Here, I use the `~=` operator for attribute texts. It allows me to use a common regular expression to combine all three of your select statements into one.

An alternative way of doing this would be to use the `,` operator for adding all selectors into one:

```
Elements allParts2 = doc.select("a[title=Flera bilder],a[title=\"\"],a[title=Bild]");
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that was one of my problems that I am not familiar so much with CSS selectors and to be honest I didnt know that I can separate them with ",".

Comment: No problem. We all learn new things every day! A good way of saying thanks on this platform is to up-vote answers that help. So I would suggest you up-vote Andy's and my responses to your question.

Comment: yes ! As soon as I get 15 reputation I will do that, not allowed to vote for now :)

Comment: Oh - I did not look at your reputation score. But yes, when you are there, you can do that.